# List of highly-regarded PHP style guides?

Tags: php, coding-style

I've recently been shaking up my coding habits and have been toying with various approaches to coding style... things like using a space between method call parentheses and the parameters they contain, how to deal with multi-line array definitions and method calls, etc.

I'm wary of creating my personal flavor of everything, though, and want to skim through some well-regarded "authoritative" style guides.  Which ones should I look at?  I've had a hard time finding much other than the Zend guide.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The [PHP Standards Recommendations](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/psr-huh/) by the [PHP Framework Interoperability Group](http://www.php-fig.org/) are a good resource. AFAIK the standards are highly regarded. They attempt to be a collection and unification of what different frameworks have decided to use as their own standards.

I would say for basic PHP coding, especially **PSR-1 and PSR-12 are well worth a read**.

> PSR-2′s purpose [was] to have a single style guide for PHP code that results in uniformly formatted shared code.
>   [The PSR-12] specification extends, expands and replaces PSR-2, the coding style guide and requires adherence to PSR-1, the basic coding standard.

There are several accepted standard recommendations.

- [PSR-1: Basic Coding Standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/)
- [PSR-12: Extended Coding Style Guide](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/)
- [All PSRs](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/)

Comment: **PSR-12** has been replaced by the [PER Coding Style](https://www.php-fig.org/per/coding-style/)

Answer (score 8):

I just use the PEAR coding standards.

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php

Answer (score 5):

This is really for Codeigniter, but it's still PHP and an easy read and I like the styles used:

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/styleguide.html