# Fetch array mysql database php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch data from database, but something is not working.

This is my code:

```
<?php

$koppla = mysql_connect("localhost","admin","","test");



// Check connection


if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


    $get = mysql_query($koppla,SELECT * FROM 123);

while ($test = mysql_fetch_array($get))
{
    echo $test['tid'];
}

mysql_close($koppla);
?> `<?php

$koppla = mysql_connect("localhost","admin","","test");



// Check connection


if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


    $get = mysql_query($koppla,SELECT * FROM 123);

while ($test = mysql_fetch_array($get))
{
    echo $test['tid'];
}

mysql_close($koppla);
?>
```

I am getting the following error while trying to fetch an array from a MySQL database. What is wrong?

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '123' (T_LNUMBER) in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 16
```

Comment: what is the 123 ? is it your table name ?

Comment: you're lost between `mysqli` and `mysql`. at place you use one other place you use the other, and you're using `mysqli_query` syntax for `mysql_query`. this `$get = mysql_query($koppla,SELECT * FROM 123);` should be like this: $get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 123");`

Comment: Why do you have this line `?> `<?php`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What was wrong

There are at least 3 errors:

- Use either `mysql_XY` or `mysqli_XY`. NOT both. See MySQL: [Choosing an API](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).
  TL;DR: Use `mysqli_*`, because `mysql_*` is deprecated.
- The `SELECT` statement in line 16 and line 39 has to be in quotes.
- The syntax of [`mysql_query`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) is

  mixed mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )

### What is correct

So line 16 has to be something like

```
$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 123", $koppla);
```

or, when you choose [`mysqli_query`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

```
$get = mysqli_query($koppla, "SELECT * FROM 123");
```

### Side notes

- **Table naming**: I would not use a table name like `123`. I don't know if this is valid SQL, but it feels wrong to not start a table with a character. See [SQLite issue with Table Names using numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4007780/562769) - I know you're using MySQL, but MySQL might have similar problems. And you might want to switch sometimes to another database system.
- **Optional arguments**: You don't need to specify the `$link_identifier` in `mysql_*` if you don't have multiple connections.
- **Style Guide**: In PHP, you usually have the curly brace `{` in the same line as the `if`. See [List of highly-regarded PHP style guides?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3638083/562769) and especially the [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html#coding-standard.coding-style.control-statements.if-else-elseif) and [PEAR section](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.control.php). This is also good for SO, because you could avoid a scrollbar in your code which makes reading your question easier.

Comment: +1 for the long detailed answer... Tell him to use mysqli as mysql_* is deprecated :)

Comment: @CodeBird: Thanks for the +1 and fixing my copy-and-paste typo in `mysqli_query`.

Comment: Cheers for the help, going to take a look at those links later as well :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$get = mysql_query($koppla,SELECT * FROM 123);
```

should be

```
$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `123`",$koppla);
```

You have this in 2 places correct them.

OH well hold on you are using mysql_query()

so it should be

```
$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `123`",$koppla);
```

https://www.php.net/mysql_query

Now going more in the code you are using `if (mysqli_connect_errno())` this is for `mysqli_connect()` you may need to see

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php as well

Answer (score 0):

`$get = mysql_query($koppla,SELECT * FROM 123);`

Shell look like this:
`$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 123", $koppla);`

A query is used to be String; and `$koppla` shell be the second parameter

Comment: I removed the my -1, now that you fixed. I tried to comment before but SO wouldn't let me...